# Unique count, array to string

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

There is my input
`{"Names":"Name1, Name2","Country":"TheCountry"}`

What i have been trying to do is count how many time a certain name appears not only in one input but also using all previous events. For that i have looked into Metrics but i cannot figure out how i might be able to do that. The first problem i have meet is that Names is a string and not an array.

I do not see how i might convert Names into an array and give it to metric. Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please check logstash configuration and add the following  `split` filter to your `logstash.yml` file. Your comma separated names will be split while ingesting the data:

```
filter {
 split {
   field => "Names"
   terminator => ","
   target => "NamesArray"
 }
}
```

And you can change your mapping. To add a new field to your type mapping like below:

```
{
  "properties": {
    ...
    "NamesArray": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

You should use `keyword` type for `NamesArray` to get correct metrics about the separated words with the blank character.

Comment: @TyLO is there any problem to not accept as an answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have looked into the doc but i cannot find what is the field properties and where should i put it. Can you please elaborate on that, that would be awesome.

Comment: You should add a filter to your logstash configuration. Please check the link. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html And then, you should change your mapping. Please check the links. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Comment: And also, I changed my answer.